# Replace and remove text in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to:

1. delete the words "ANOS" and "ANO";
2. replace "A" to "TO"; and
3. replace "<1ano" to "0 to 1".

Example: "10 A 19 ANOS" to  "10 to 19"

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'FAIXA_ETARIA': ['10 A 19 ANOS',' 20 A 29 ANOS', '30 A 39 ANOS', '40 A 49 ANOS',
                                    '50 A 59 ANOS', ' 60 A 69 ANOS', '70 A 79 ANOS', '80 A 89 ANOS',
                                      '<1ANO'],
                     'Count': [3, 8, 28, 7, 15, 9, 3, 5, 3]})
```

PS: My database presents many columns, I would like this procedure to be performed **only** in column **"FAIXA_ETARIA"**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does my answer make sense?  I'm using regular expressions for flexibility.  If you'd like, check out `https://regex101.com/` to practice.  I think there's a Python implementation available (on the left side of the window under "FLAVOR").

Comment: @MarkMoretto your code works! Thanks for yout help and the link, I need to pratice this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one possible way:

```
data["FAIXA_ETARIA"] \
    .str.replace(r"ANO\w?", "") \ # Regex for ANO plus an optional single character
    .str.replace(r"A", "TO") \ # Replace a single character
    .str.replace(r"<\w?", "0 to 1") # Regex for < and non-greedy multiple characters.
```

Output:

```
0     10 TO 19 
1     20 TO 29 
2     30 TO 39 
3     40 TO 49 
4     50 TO 59 
5     60 TO 69 
6     70 TO 79 
7     80 TO 89 
8        0 to 1
Name: FAIXA_ETARIA, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate threw the entrys in your array and then use the `replace()` method of python.
Example:

```
message = "Hello there"
custom = message.replace("there", "kvratto")
```

The result would be "Hello kvratto".

In your case you've got a dictionary. So you can get the specific entrys with `dictionaryname['columnname']`. You can put the result in a new variable and then you can handle it like an array.

I hope that helps enough!

Comment: Thanks for your help, @MarkMoretto and @LinusDehner!

Answer (score 1):

Or, just extract the digit, and join with ' to ':

```py
data['FAIXA_ETARIA'] = data['FAIXA_ETARIA'].str.findall('\d+').str.join(' to ')
cond = data['FAIXA_ETARIA']  == '1'
data.loc[cond, 'FAIXA_ETARIA'] = '0 to 1'
```

```
0    10 to 19
1    20 to 29
2    30 to 39
3    40 to 49
4    50 to 59
5    60 to 69
6    70 to 79
7    80 to 89
8      0 to 1
Name: FAIXA_ETARIA, dtype: object
```